# Solrj Hello world - /solr/update Not Found

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I followed the [tutorial to use Solrj](https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Solr/Chapter_04_-_Solrj_Example.jsp) (and updated to most recent Solrj version 6.0.1),

**1) Downloaded [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/downloads.html)**

**2) Started solr server from command line using**

> solr-6.0.1\bin>solr start

Seems everything OK, http://localhost:8983/solr/ can be viewed in a browser

**3) Executed HelloWorld Solrj code**:

```
public class SolrClientHelloWorld {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            HttpSolrClient server = new HttpSolrClient (
                    "http://localhost:8983/solr/");
            SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
            doc.addField("id", "tsetstst3r4", 1.0f);
            doc.addField("name", "doc1", 1.0f);
            doc.addField("price", 10);
            server.add(doc);        
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**

> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:
>   Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: Expected mime type
>   application/octet-stream but got text/html.   
>   Error 404 Not Found
>
> ### HTTP ERROR
>   404
>
> Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
>
> ```
>     Not
> Found
> ```
>
> at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:545)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
>     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:173)
>     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:138)
>     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:152)
>     at SolrClient.main(SolrClient.java:16)

**Environment**: Windows 10, java version "1.8.0_91"

Did I miss something to configure on the Solr server?

Related answers that that seems gives no solution:

Answer (score 3):

### Two things needs to be done before indexing.

1.You must have a core or collection to index the data in SOLR.
2.You must add the core/collection name in the SOLR base URL

### Example

### 1. Start and create core/collection in SOLR

### SOLR Standalone mode (core):

```
bin>solr start
bin>solr create_core -c test -p 8983 -d basic_configs
```

### SOLR Cloud mode (collection):

```
bin>solr start -cloud
bin>solr create -c test -p 8983 -d basic_configs
```

Note : Kindly update your fields in `schema.xml`

### 2.SOLRJ

Update the above line from

```
HttpSolrClient server = new HttpSolrClient (
                    "http://localhost:8983/solr/");
```

To

```
HttpSolrClient server = new HttpSolrClient (
                    "http://localhost:8983/solr/test");
```

Note : Here my core/collection name is `test`

Answer (score 0):

There is needed to also create a core, for example with the name test:

> solr create -c test

and access the url accordingly

```
HttpSolrClient server = new HttpSolrClient (
                    "http://localhost:8983/solr/test");
```

Answer (score 0):

For using Solr as a search engine you have to make a proper core with required field setting in schema.xml file.

you can also use the command for same

```
bin/solr create -help

bin/solr create [-c name] [-d confdir] [-n configName] [-shards #] [-replicationFactor #] [-p port]
```

by using above command you can create on core named with "test"

```
bin/solr create -c test
```

Then you can use the core by referring

```
HttpSolrClient server = new HttpSolrClient (
                "http://localhost:8983/solr/test");
```